# Is there invalid state of Input range?

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, range

I need to define custom HTML5 form validation styles in my application's design system like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#server-side). But I don’t know how to apply `:invalid` state to an `<input type="range">`.

```js
console.log($('#test').val());
$('#test').val(50);
console.log($('#test').val());
```

```css
.valid-message,
.invalid-message {
  display: none;
}

.input:valid ~ .valid-message {
  display: block;
  color: green;
}

.input:invalid ~ .invalid-message {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control">
  <input type="range" class="input range" id="test" min="1" max="20">
  <p class="valid-message">This is valid</p>
  <p class="invalid-message">This is invalid</p>
</div>
```

Is there invalid state of Input range? How can I reproduce that state?

Comment: Maybe you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:out-of-range

Comment: I did a bit of testing, but I can't seem to create an invalid range input. Setting the value to an out of range one (including by adding a `value="50"` attribute to the source) results in the value being snapped to the min or max value. ( In other words, such an input is always valid. However, I'd love to be shown wrong!

Comment: I think @MrLister is right, you can't set invalid value on client side. From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#Value) "If an attempt is made to set the value lower than the minimum, it is set to the minimum. Similarly, an attempt to set the value higher than the maximum results in it being set to the maximum."

Comment: @SuperDJ Thanks, but as @mr-lister said, I can not reproduce the `:out-of-range`.

Comment: For testing purposes, if you want to simulate what would happen if those states could be triggered (during debugging), just give the input `type="number"`. Then it works similarly, except you can give it an invalid value.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explanation. Also I'm looking for necessity to design an invalid style for the range itself: like `.range:invalid {...}`

Comment: Hey, if you want to know why you would need to style an invalid range input, even though we've just shown that ranges can't be invalid, that's a different question! And the answer is, of course, older browsers. Browsers that can't handle range inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range controls can be invalid only if `setCustomValidity()` is called.

Refer to the specification; https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-value-default-range

It never be [`valueMissing`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#dom-validitystate-valuemissing) state because it has **default value**.
It never be [`rangeUnderflow`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#dom-validitystate-rangeunderflow), [`rangeOverflow`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#dom-validitystate-rangeoverflow), [`stepMismatch`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#dom-validitystate-stepmismatch) because UA must adjust the value according to the specification.

Comment: I could be confirmed the invalid state by `document.getElementById("test").setCustomValidity("Error message")`. I learned new here, I can ignore designing the invalid style of range input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But I did not know how to apply `:invalid` state to an `<input type="range">`.

Actually **you can't apply** `:invalid` state to an `<input type="range">`, because the value will always be set between the `min` and `max` values, and you can't force it to be out of range it will be automatically updated to fit the `range`.

If you check the **[MDN `<input type="range">` specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#Value)** in the **Value** section, you can see that:

> If an attempt is made to set the value lower than the minimum, it is set to the minimum. Similarly, an attempt to set the value higher than the maximum results in it being set to the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

By testing on Chrome and Firefox I reason that no `:invalid` state can occur for `type="range"`. Any value out of range is automatically increased or decreased to `min` or `max`.

Mozilla sets the [defaults to 0 and 100](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#Specifying_the_minimum_and_maximum) and [bad or no values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#Value) are replaced by average value.

[W3C about input range](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/input.range.html)

Comment: Can I see the specifications ? W3C or etc.

Comment: @Alex I've rewritten my answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

To have the range input in an invalid state just set the steps attribute.
For `<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" />` a value of 0.25 is invalid.
But according to MDN, most browsers might round the value to the nearest valid one.

Seems like Firefox doesn't do this, as my range input is highlighted in red when programatically setting some value that doesn't conform to (min + n * steps)

[MDN - HTML attribute: step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step)